# How do I un-install Ubuntu TV

Tags: uninstall, ubuntu-tv

Before I jump into the deep end of the pool and install this *wonderful* looking media app. My concerns are it's stability and my ability to revert my system back to it's pre-ubuntuTV state.

Are there any detailed 'un-install' instructions? or is my best bet to just do a complete backup and restore if anything goes amuk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it has been packaged correctly, by installing UbuntuTV using the deb package from webupd8, you should (in theory) be able to ppa-purge the PPA and this would restore your system.

i.e.

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:nilarimogard/test3
sudo apt-get remove unity-lens-video
```

If you see the following error message `sudo: ppa-purge: command not found` then install the `ppa-purge` package:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

However, as all PPAs are potentially destructive, a drive-image would be prudent to make, especially as UbuntuTV makes underlying changes to Ubuntu2D.

I've done some limited testing installing and ppa-purge the package.  From initial testing, ubuntu-2D works correctly after uninstalling - i.e. the same packages upgraded to v5 are downgraded to v4.x that is standard in oneiric.

However - the warning should be still applicable - drive-image your hard-drive.  Use it as an excuse to perform that regular backup procedure we all keep putting off... :)

---

Linked Question:

1. [How do I install Ubuntu TV on my computer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94089/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-tv-on-my-computer)

Comment: +1, especially for the part about putting off backups. [Another popular question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/94421/is-there-a-way-to-recover-files-from-a-storage-device-partially-overwritten-with) right now has already inspired me to do that when I get home.

Comment: `sudo: ppa-purge: command not found` may be worth mentioning `ppa-purge` has to be installed.

Comment: I am constantly editing (or at least looking for places I can edit) questions but I never think to edit Answers.

Comment: After un-installing using the described method I am now receiving `unmet dependencies` errors. Is this expected?

Comment: I've looked on webupd8 and no-one is reporting the same.  I've just rechecked on by virtualbox install.  No issues. Were you connected to the internet when you did a ppa-purge? What happens if you do `sudo apt-get --reinstall install unity-2d`?  Please can you post the errors (copy and paste) via the website `paste.ubuntu.com`

Comment: The solution was to run `sudo apt-get install -f` the errors are [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/800953/)

Answer (score 0):

There are good instructions both for installing and uninstalling Ubuntu TV at www.WebUpd8.org, [HERE](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/how-to-install-ubuntu-tv-from-ppa.html).  You're correct: removal is important!