# How do I install Ubuntu TV on my PC and booth Ubuntu and Ubuntu TV?

Tags: ubuntu-tv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu TV on my computer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94089/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-tv-on-my-computer)

How do I install Ubuntu TV on my PC TV and booth Ubuntu and Ubuntu TV?